# Multiple conditions in while loop and finding the index when a condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I need help with two kinds of while loops please.

1) This code is in multiple files so I can't post. I have to make a game stop when either one of the players have won at least 10 points. The other condition is to stop the game when the difference of their scores are at least 3. I tried:

```
while playerA < 10 or playerB < 10 and abs(playerA-playerB) < 3:
```

But it does not work. I also tried to add an if statement at the end to break the loop if playerA==10 and playerB==10 and many other things but the program either won't run of will keep running even after the conditions are met.

2) I don't even know how to do this one so any help would be appreciated. I have a list and a threshold and I have to find the sum of the elements in the list until it is less than or equal to the threshold. For example:

```
list = [4,1,6,3,6,5,2]
threshold = 10
```

My while loop can only count the sum of the first two elements since adding the third element will return a number larger than the threshold. I have to print the index where it happens.

Thank you!

Comment: Change the `or` to and `and` in the while loop.

Comment: I've done that but the program stops even when the players have less than 10 points. It only meets the condition where the difference is 3 or more.

Comment: But its one or the other right? So if either player scores more than 10 or if the difference is greater than 3. Or do they need to get to 10 points first?

Comment: Both the conditions have to be met. Atleast one player has to win 10 points and the difference between their scores have to be atleast 3 or more. For example if playerA wins 10 points then playerB can only have 7 points or less.

Comment: Oops one sec I'll fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Parenthesis help but Boolean logic can be confusing for `while` loops. The  best part is to break it into the parts. For the loop to stop both sides must be `False` in the following condition, so one player must be over 10 AND the difference must be greater than 3. If you still had trouble you could always just do an `if` inside that loop that `break`s because at least the logic isn't backwards.

```
while (playerA < 10 and playerB < 10) or abs(playerA-playerB) < 3:
```

Another option (which may help you) is break out the checking logic so things aren't backwards:

```
def can_continue(playerA, playerB):
    if (playerA > 10 or playerB > 10) and abs(playerA - playerB) >= 3:
        return False
    return True
```

Then do:

```
while can_continue(playerA, playerB):
```

2) That loop may be a little tricky but you just need to short circuit.

```
my_list = [4,1,6,3,6,5,2] # list wasn't a good variable name.
threshold = 10
score_sum = 0
for index, ele in enumerate(my_list):
    if score_sum + ele > threshold:
        break
    score_sum += ele
print(score_sum) # 5
print(index) # We stopped at index 2
print(my_list[:index]) # We can splice with that index [4, 1]
```

Comment: 1) Thank you, the parenthesis are making it work better than before although it sometimes doesn't meet both conditions. I'll try the other method and see how that works. 2) Thanks for this as well! How would I get the index of the element where it stops? Also, is there a way to do it with slicing?

Comment: It may be an off by one. You may need a `<=` instead of a `<`.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I think it's doing that only when neither of the conditions can be met, which I guess is a possibility. Could I please ask you to help me with something else? It's in my comment above.

Comment: What comment are you referring to?

Comment: 2) Thanks for this as well! How would I get the index of the element where it stops? Also, is there a way to do it with slicing?